# How to send nested objects with router.navigate()?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm working on a project in Reac Native Expo and using "expo-router" to navigate between pages.
I need to send a nested object array from one screen to another.

My object structure is something like this:

```
item: {
   id: '123',
   name: 'name',
   nestedObjectArray: [{id: 1, name: 'name'}, {id: 2, name: 'name'}, {id: 3, name: 'name'}],
}
```

I've used router.navigate(`({pathname: 'path/to/screen', params: item}) but in the other screen I'm receiving this:

```
item: {
   id: '123',
   name: 'name',
   nestedObjectArray: [object Object], [object Object], [object Object],
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the output in `JSON.stringify(json)` to verify that the `[object Object]` is what you're expecting?  Odds are it will come through just fine.